# I have NumPy installed, but I can't import it

Tags: python, numpy, importerror

I am trying to use NumPy in Python interactive mode, but I am having trouble importing it.

I've installed NumPy using the

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

command, but when I open the Python Shell and type `import numpy` then it gives me

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I tried running the `pip install` command again, and it tells me:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\sean\appdata\local\programs\python
\python36-32\lib\site-packages (1.14.4)
```

Here's what I get when I try to find the Python path:

```
>>>import sys
>>>for p in sys.path:
...    print (p)
...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_34\python36.zip
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_34\DLLs
C:\program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_34\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_34
C:\Users\sean\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_34\lib\site-packages
```

I don't know what the problem is, and after searching on this community and online in general, many people seem to be having similar issues but resolved it by modifying their path. Could anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: You may have accidentally installed Python twice.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the feedback. I wasn't aware of that possibility. I'll try and do more research on that issue and see if I can solve it.

Comment: I think you have two version of python. as you see, there is one on `Roaming` directory and another one is for `VS`